# From datatable to Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datatable

Is it possible to populate an entity with the contents of a DataTable?

Comment: Nope. AFAIK looping through the DataTable will be the only option

Comment: Hmm maybe there is a better way. I am reading a spreadsheet in to a dataTable and then wanted to use that to populate a SQL Entity. I am going about this wrong?

Comment: @Brian Read the spread sheet straight into the SQL Entity?

Comment: @giddy I didn't think you could read directly from spreadsheets to entities?

Comment: @Brian lol No I mean't traverse the data from the spreadsheet and put it into the entity.

Comment: @giddy Sorry but could you give me an example of what you mean please?

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for:
[Converting DataTable to Entities][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355371/from-datatable-to-entity

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for but it should work; there is a [.AsEnumerable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) extension method which you can then use to project the row into a new entity.

```
var products = productTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new Product 
{
    ProductID = row.Field<int>("ProductID"),
    Name = row.Field<string>("Name"),
    CreatedDate = row.Field<DateTime>("CreatedDate")
});
```

As far as I know the `.Field<T>()` method doesn't do any type conversion so if the column hasn't had the type set you will need to do the conversion yourself.

Comment: Well... in my case it was exactly what I was looking for. I was missing the `AsEnumerable()` and those twists with the `Field<>()` afterwards. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is what you are looking for:
[Converting DataTable to Entities](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/157601/Working-with-Entities-instead-of-DataTable-Objects)